# How to show the text of an UITextField in an UILabel?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uilabel

I am building an interface, where I can add events like in a calendar.
In the AddAEventViewController I have Buttons to set the starttime, duration and recurrence.
Every time you press a button a viewcontroller comes up with a UIDatePicker, where you can set your time. The picked component is than displayed in a UITextField. Now when I press the Done-Button, it dismisses the ModalViewController and I am back to my AddAEventViewController. Next to the Durationbutton e.g. is  a UILabel, where I want to show now the just picked and in the textfield shown duration.
How do I get access to the AddEventViewController out of an other ViewController? I tried to alloc and init a new one there, but it didnt work!

```
- (IBAction)pressedDoneButton:(id)sender {

 _mainAddWishViewController.labelDuration.text=textFieldDuration.text;

 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

Can someone help me please!
Thank you Jules

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do this, all of them documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html). Reading and understanding them will help you a lot in iOS software development.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this.  Here is one that is fairly straightforward.

In the "child" viewController, add a delegate property and set it to the parent view controller.

Then in your Done button handler, do something like:

```
[self.delegate performSelector:@selector(didComplete) withObject:self]
```

In the parent view controller, define a method as follows:

```
- (void) didComplete: (YourSubViewControllerClass *) sender   
{
    self.labelDuration.text = sender.textFieldDuration.text
}
```

Basically, this implements an informal protocol whereby the subViewController informs the main view controller that it is finished and input values are available.

Note that if you cancel out of the subViewController, don't send the didComplete message.